# Problem with C#: StartIndex cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: startIndex

Tags: c#, instagram

This is my code :

```
public static async void Download()
{
    InstagramDownloadMachine instagramDownloadMachine = new InstagramDownloadMachine();
    await instagramDownloadMachine.DownloadToPath(@"https://www.insta.com/p/CLL_c2egcL9/", "img.jpg");
}
```

When I execute it, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
> Parameter name: startIndex'

(I use this code to download insta videos BTW)

So this is full-code of dll:

```
    private String fileExtension, fileKey;
    private const String imgExtension = ".jpg";
    private const String videoExtension = ".mp4";
    private const String videoKey = "video_url\": \"";
    private const String imgKey = "display_url\": \"";
    public async Task<Stream> Download(String url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string fileUrl = GetFileUrl(responseFromServer);
        var fileStream = GetFileStream(fileUrl);
        return fileStream;
    }
    public async Task DownloadToPath(String url, String path)
    {
        var stream = await Download(url);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
    private Stream GetFileStream(String url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest fileRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = fileRequest.GetResponse();
        return response.GetResponseStream();
    }

    private String GetFileUrl(String html)
    {
        String fileUrl = null;

        if (html.Contains("video_url"))
        {
            fileExtension = videoExtension;
            fileKey = videoKey;
        }
        else
        {
            fileExtension = imgExtension;
            fileKey = imgKey;
        }

        var auxIndex = html.IndexOf(fileKey);
        var partial = html.Substring(auxIndex);
        var endOfUrl = partial.IndexOf(fileExtension) + fileExtension.Length;
        fileUrl = html.Substring(auxIndex, endOfUrl);
        fileUrl = fileUrl.Substring(fileKey.Length);
        return fileUrl;
    }
}
```

}

and idk that is wrong with startindex /:

Comment: and 1more thing,can use it for xamarin.forms?(have external .dll component ;D

Comment: I presume this error is being thrown inside the DownloadToPath() method. If that's inside a DLL then it's going to be hard to solve. If it isn't inside a DLL then you need to post the code for it for us to be able to help.

Comment: What is the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: full code added

Comment: As an aside, if at all possible use HttpClient instead of manually constructing WebRequests.. You'll thank yourself later. Also no need to CopyTo a memory stream only to then write all bytes to file. Open a file stream and copy to that instead of doing the work twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the exception is coming from html.Substring(auxIndex) line inside GetFileUrl method. The Substring method overload you are using takes the startIndex as the only parameter hence your exception says it can't be negative. The auxIndex variable has value -1 because the fileKey was not found in your html. You should put a condition there to handle this scenario.

More explanation:

[IndexOf reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0)

[Substring reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0)

```
var auxIndex = html.IndexOf(fileKey);/* This method will return -1 if fileKey is not found in html. So auxIndex variable will have -1.*/
    var partial = html.Substring(auxIndex); /* This Substring method expects the parameter (auxIndex) to be non-negative, So if the above IndexOf method returned -1, auxIndex will be -1 and that would cause the Substring method to throw error. */
```

You could have a check inside the method to see whether auxIndex is non-negative e.g.

```
if(auxIndex >= 0)
{
 /* means your fileKey was found in the html, so you can put the rest of the code here*/
var partial = html.Substring(auxIndex);
//....other lines
}
else
{
/* you need to put logic to handle this case where fileKey was not found in html*/
}
```

Comment: i dont get it,can you explain more?

Comment: I edited my answer with more explanation. Hope it helps